# How to display nested data on the DOM?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, axios

Trying to fetch data from an API and add it to the DOM

Specifically, an array that contains objects.

Below is an example of what the API returns in the console.

[image: json returned from API]

I’m using a for loop and a for…in loop to access the array within the object

Code below

```js
const getNews = document.getElementById('btn')

heyThere = () => {
    axios.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=APIKEY')
        .then(function (response) {
            for (let i = 0; i <= response.data.articles.length; i++) {
                for (key in response.data.articles[i]) {
                    ham.innerHTML = (response.data.articles)
                }
            }
            console.log(response)
            console.log(typeof response)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
}

getNews.addEventListener('click', heyThere)
```

The above code prints the following to the DOM

[image]

What’s the correct way to access the full list of articles(20 articles) and print them to the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below prints the articles to the DOM as a list.

```js
heyThere = () => {
    axios.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=APIKEY')
        .then(function (response) {
            let news = response.data.articles
            for (let i = 0, len = news.length; i < len; i++) {
                console.log(news[i])
                let li = document.createElement('li')
                li.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(news[i].title)
                document.querySelector('#ham').appendChild(li)
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
}

getNews.addEventListener('click', heyThere)
```

Below are the articles printed to the page

[image]

Altering the response with dot notation allows one to return a list of URLs, authors, etc. For example, `li.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(news[i].url)`

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the specific properties of `response.data.articles[i]` that you want to display, and create the desired HTML for each of them. Something like:

```js
const getNews = document.getElementById('btn')

heyThere = () => {
  axios.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=APIKEY')
    .then(function(response) {
      let html = '';
      response.data.articles.each(article => {
        html += '<div class="article">';
        html += `<div class="author">${article.author}</div>`;
        html += `<div class="description">${article.description}</div>`;
        html += '</div>';
      });
      ham.innerHTML = html;
      console.log(response)
      console.log(typeof response)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
}

getNews.addEventListener('click', heyThere)
```